# How to debug a laptop keyboard hardware issue?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, keyboard-layout

How can I debug a laptop keyboard hardware issue? Basically, how can I figure out what could be or what exactly is broken?

As example, I'm having an issue and would like to solve it, perhaps. What I know is that when it broke I was there. First I only thought "v" broke, later it turns out, well at least for me it would make sense that in the keyboard matrix an entire "row" would not be functioning.

So, I can't press the following keys at the same time anymore without one of them being ghosted, might that I couldn't list all:

"q3t", "ur", "ot", "cb" (not sure about cb though I think it was possible before), "wrz"

When holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> doesn't work

When holding right <kbd>Alt</kbd> or "alt gr" "4" and "5" their unicode combination is not working. However for both if I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> and let go of <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing <kbd>B</kbd>, it works same if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> fast, which makes sense.

So yeah that's that

**More description about the issue:**

Now, here's a thing which starts to go into a weird situation. So I know that there are circuits and stuff and it doesn't make sense to me that a circuit like a line __________ would just have broken off like this *******/*******___ I don't think so because that would make "v" not work at all. Because sometimes the "v" works and that is not because of "hard pressure".

Sometimes there's like a "wave", where a bunch of "v" start to appear which goes like this in the text input, like as if I would be pressing it:

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

right?

So when that happens, if I press any other key as example on the Numpad or even <kbd>F1</kbd>. If I do that the "v" stops "spamming". But sometimes it also stops on its own, without me doing anything on the keyboard.

What I was able to try, was that, when that "wave" appears if I press a key on the "On-screen keyboard" it doesn't stop the "spam". I am not able to test what happens with an external keyboard, but I assume it is a hardware issue of the laptop keyboard somewhere, just don't know where.

Now here comes the weird part, sometimes after the wave or, well there are moments where everything works again, the "v" and all of the combinations would work again. But how?

Remember when I talked about the circuit line, if it is broken? There's now way it gets unbroken, something else must be happening I just don't know what. I don't understand if the cable is starting to walk inside my computer or something, it just doesn't make sense to me.

I'm able to make a "wave" appear when attempting to press these non working combinations "q3t" HOWEVER that is not guaranteed. Sometimes just a "v" appears when I do that.

Then when I use "v" it works for a while and then it doesn't work anymore, means it goes back to the status where, when I press it, it doesn't do anything and when it doesn't work anymore all the other combos don't work anymore as well, like "q3t".

So yeah, what exactly is going on? How is it possible that "v" sometimes works or not? How can I debug that? Because I'm not sure if it's worth it trying to open it and then what, unplug and replug it?

The model I have is an ASUS ROG GL752VW. The keyboard layout is basically a 96% keyboard.

What is going on? How can this be explained in electricity knowledge? How can it be debug? And how did this issue even happen?

I tried to reinstall the standard keyboard driver. I believe that this issue is so good that if explained it could help others figuring out what is going on.

Comment: Have you tested if the behavior is the same when running a different OS (e.g. a live Linux system booted from USB-stick or DVD)? Before blaming the hardware it is a good idea to make 100% sure it is really a hardware issue. Also testing with an external USB keyboard is an option, too.

Comment: what about BIOS?

Comment: There is not a single wire going to each key from the microcontroler. That'd be really wasteful. Basically, there are collumns and rows, and when you press a key, you connect them. The microcontroller loops between all of the rows and columns in order (1-1, 1-2, 1-3, ... , 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, etc...), and registers a keypress when it notices a connection.+

Comment: +Because of this, is a trace is broken of shorted, weird things might occur, becuase there is no such thing as the "v" cable. The V letter is in a row and a column, and if, for example, the row is broken, the V won't work, and other letters will break too without apparent reason. And if the issue is more complicated, like a short, there can be unexpected behaviour . See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard#Control_processor)

Comment: @milo8505 How is it possible though that from doing nothing, the "v" just starts to appear or work? Could it be that the microcontroller might be malfunctioning? Is the microcontroller maybe also dependent on a driver? Could it be that the microcontroller can be tricked, is the microcontroller choosing which row?

Comment: The microcontroller shouldn't depend on a driver, and it's hardwired to perform its function, so you can't trick it. You should test that it is actually a hardware issue (by using another OS), and if it is, replace the keyboard

Comment: @milo8505 What about testing it on BIOS?

Comment: There isn't a place for you to write in BIOS. Create a live Linux USB and boot from it. It's very easy